# Prices too accurate in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, currency, invoice

I am currently building an intranet for work which has invoices. I am currently writing tests for it to make sure the VAT sums up correctly, etc.

I have noticed that on some amounts, that Rails/Ruby seems to be more accurate that it needs to be. I get this: `expected there to be content "2586.6099999999997"`. Notice the `099999999997` when it should be `1`.

In my DB migration file I have this - `t.decimal :price, :precision => 8, :scale => 2`

In my test I am only trying to add up two values, `949` and `1637.61` which should sum `2586.61` not `2586.60999...`.

What would be the problem?

Should I be using Decimal or should I use integer?

EDIT: The spec code is basically just this `page.should have_content(item1.price + 1637.61)`. The item1 is using FactoryGirl.

I get the same problem when manually putting 949 or 949.00 in the test like this `page.should have_content(949 + 1637.61)`

```
item1 = FactoryGirl.create(:item, :quantity => 1, :price => 949.00, :description => "macbook for 949")
```

Comment: For monetary values, NEVER use  float. Store the amounts as cents/pennies in integer fields, or as decimal types.

Comment: Adding the spec code which I'm having problems with in the question

Comment: I'd try making the literals in those specs BigDecimals since your db appears to be using decimal already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your database column is actually functioning just like it should, since it's a `decimal` column. The problem is in your spec's code:

```
page.should have_content(item1.price + 1637.61)
```

So if the price is 949.00, it's doing `949.00 + 1637.61`. Remember that this is independent of your database column, it's just ruby code. So `949.00 + 1637.61` is being evaluated as adding a float (`1637.61`) to a decimal value (`949.00`), which returns a float, hence the `2586.60999`. So the spec is expecting `2586.60999`, but the view is showing `2586.61` (as it should, since they're decimal columns).

If you can just use strings and fixed values in your spec, that might be an easy fix:

```
page.should have_content("2586.61")
```

Alternatively, you can make sure you're keeping everything in decimal format, something like:

```
page.should have_content(item1.price + BigDecimal.new("1637.61"))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Just one thing, I am using `number_to_currency` and so it puts a comma `,` for values over 999.99 like you'd expect so it has `2,586.61` but the test it trying to find `2586.61` and fails.

Comment: In that case, you would either need to use the string method and just hard code in "2,586.61", or use the `number_to_currency` helper in your spec file too (I'm not sure if view helpers are available by default in specs, but I'm sure there's a way)

Comment: You can directly access it with `ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(...)`

Comment: I will just hard code the value in for the moment. Thanks for your help! :)